# JSON and JAVA (android)

Tags: java, android, json

в моем приложения (андроид) я получаю с сервера json. После при оброботке

```
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json);

        this.product_name = object.getString("name");
        this.product_price = object.getString("price");
        this.product_locaton = object.getString("location");
        this.product_id = object.getString("id");
        this.image_url = object.getString("image_url");

        isOkey = true;
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        isOkey = false;
    }
```

если такого элемента в строке нет то меня тупа выбрасывает с приложения из-за JSONException. Как можно проверить строку "Является ли она json"? может какойто метод есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять параметр через метод `object.optString("name", "defaultValue")` таким образом даже если поля с таким ключем нет, `exception`a` не будет, вернется дефолтное значение

Answer (score 0):

У объекта JSONObject есть метод .has("name") - видимо он вам и нужен.

Comment: в параметр нужно писать ключь или саму строку?

Comment: и для JSONArray есть такое?

Answer (score 0):

А еще лучше вызвать `object.getString("name", defaultValue)`, где defaultValue может быть ваша строка, а может быть и null, в зависмости от того что вам нужно по бизнес логике.

Это позволит вам избежать кучи проверок, в случае ответа выше.

Comment: object это jsonObject? если да то метода с такими параметрами нет